# Remove SID=XYZ from URL but retain all other parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Ive been looking to remove the "SID=xxxxxx" parameter from a url that contains various dynamic parameters.

example:

From: https://www.example.com/category1?SID=r54m3kt32bcadh9vsohk5la290&style=298&location=b&filter=23

To: https://www.example.com/category1?style=298&location=b&filter=23

The URL's will vary and all other subsequent parameters will vary:

https://www.example.com/category1/?SID=r54m3kt32bcadh9vsohk5la290&size=xl&style=45
https://www.example.com/?SID=r54m3kt32bcadh9vsohk5la290&colour=red
https://www.example.com/category1/?SID=r54m3kt32bcadh9vsohk5la290

I have added this to the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*)SID(.*)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [QSA,R=301,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

However it does remove the SID parameter, but unfortunately in every instance it removes everything after the SID parameter. so the following URL:
https://www.example.com/category1/category2?SID=r54m3kt32bcadh9vsohk5la290&style=298&location=b&filter=23

Now looks like this:
https://www.example.com/category1/category2
but I want to retain all the other parameters

Ay advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:(.*)&)?SID=[^&]+(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That one gave me a 404 error but with a few tweaks it worked: 

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?SID=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]

This one worked perfectly on our server.

Comment: That version will result in invalid query strings depending on the situation.

Comment: I fail to see what should be the issue with my approach. Could you please post the exact URL you tried which resulted in a 404? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.example.com/product/wines/red?SID=fj98H9s9J1Ssnc3o32dh5&bottle_size=4&country=16&price=20-30